# Error when storing Strings in Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to store strings in a numpy array, however, I keep getting this error "TypeError: data type not understood" on the line where I define J. I have to store these 4 values in a 2x2 matrix so I believe I can not use chararray. Is there any other way around this?

I'm a noob and want to learn so the more you can explain the better!

Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import math as math
L1=1
L2=1.5 * L1
theta = 40 * math.pi / 180

#initial guesses

L3 = 1.5
alpha = 30 * math.pi / 180
epsilon = 1
n = 0

while epsilon > 0.0001:
    g1 = L1 * math.cos(theta) + L2 * math.cos(alpha) - L3
    dg1dalpha = -L2 * math.sin(alpha)
    dg1dL3 = -1;

    g2 = L1 * math.sin(theta) - L2 * math.sin(alpha)
    dg2dalpha = -L2 * math.cos(alpha);
    dg2dL3 = 0

    J = np.array(['dg1dalpha', 'dg1dL3'], ['dg2dalpha', 'dg2dL3'])

    s = np.array([alpha], [L3]) - J/np.array([g1], [g2])

    epsilon_alpha = abs(s[1] - alpha)

    epsilon_L3 = abs(s[2] - L3)

    epsilon = max(epsilon_alpha, epsilon_L3)

    alpha = s[1]

    L3 = s[2]

    n = n + 1

print(n, alpha, L3)
```

Comment: Why are you storing strings? it looks to me like `dg1dalpha` is a variable name. Don't you want to store its value? As in `J = np.array([[dg1dalpha, dg1dL3], [dg2dalpha, dg2dL3]])`.

Comment: If you really want to, you can store a string array, but you're missing a pair of brackets in this line: `J = np.array([['dg1dalpha', 'dg1dL3'], ['dg2dalpha', 'dg2dL3']])`, which is the cause of your error. You passed two arguments to `np.array`, when you meant to pass one list of lists. The second argument is expected to be `dtype` which you don't need.

Comment: Can you explain why I need the extra pair of brackets? That's where my mistake was? I though that ( ) would be sufficient for the array( ) command. Thanks

Comment: If you look at [numpy.array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) you see that the first argument is an array like object, subsequent arguments are various options. So `np.array([1,2],[3,4])` gives an error as the second argument is the wrong format, `np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])` creates a 2D array.

Comment: @Justin, did @Salix's comment help? In their example, `[3,4]` is the second argument, which `array` is interpreting as the data type for the first argument `[1,2]`. I'm still concerned that you don't actually want strings in your arrays though.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for all the help I understand now that my format was wrong and it was looking for an argument that I didn't want to pass it. @askewchan you're right I don't want strings in my arrays. I misunderstood something! Thanks